# Deploy socket.io app into a domain ?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i'm new here. Just starting with socket.io and node.js, and I tried to upload the project to a subfolder on my domain, but i can't find anything about subdirectories and socket.io (I saw some questions, but it didn't work for me) Thie domain is "http://www.nicolasrivero.com/2" It's working on localhost. Here is my code...

The console log error is this

```
http://nicolasrivero.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1429923179530-0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I think it's obvius, socket.io is trying to connect with nicolasrivero.com and not with nicolasrivero.com/2 ... Any help would be appreciated (Sorry for my bad english, lol)

Index.html (head)

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Index.html (body)

```
<input autofocus id="name" placeholder="Nombre">

<textarea  placeholder="caja de texto" id="area" style="width:220px; height:200px; background-color:white;  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;"></textarea>

<input autofocus id="msj" placeholder="Input name" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('enviar').click()" >        

<button id="enviar" type="button" onclick="enviarmsj()"> Enviar </button>
```

Index.html (js)

```
<script>


    var socket = io.connect();

    document.getElementById('area').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('msj').focus();


    function enviarmsj(){

        input = document.getElementById('msj').value;
        nombre = document.getElementById('name').value;
        console.log(input);
        socket.emit('miMensajeEnviado', input, nombre);
        document.getElementById('msj').value = "";

    }


socket.on('mensajeEnviado', function(input, nombre){

        console.log(input);
        document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = document.getElementById("area").innerHTML + nombre + ": " + input + "\n";


});

</script>
```

Aaaand in my server.js

```
var serverPort = 3000;
var http = require('http').createServer(MyServer);
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
var nSight=0;

var contentTypes={
    ".html":"text/html",
    ".css":"text/css",
    ".js":"application/javascript",
    ".png":"image/png",
    ".jpg":"image/jpeg",
    ".ico":"image/x-icon",
    ".m4a":"audio/mp4",
    ".oga":"audio/ogg"
};
http.listen(3000);

function MyServer(request,response){
var filePath = '.' + request.url;
if (filePath == './')
    filePath = './index.html';

var extname = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('.'));
var contentType = contentTypes[extname];
if(!contentType)
    contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
//console.log((new Date()) + ' Serving ' + filePath + ' as ' + contentType);

fs.exists(filePath, function(exists){
    if(exists){
        fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content){
            if(error){
                response.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                response.end('<h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>');
            }
            else{
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                response.end(content, 'utf-8');
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        response.end('<h1>404 Not Found</h1>');
    }
});
}


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.player = nSight++;    
    console.log(socket.id + ' connected as player ' + socket.player);    

    socket.on('miMensajeEnviado', function(input, nombre){ 


    io.sockets.emit("mensajeEnviado", input, nombre); 

})

socket.on('disconnect', function(){

    console.log('Player' + socket.player + ' disconnected.');

});
});
```

Comment: FYI, your code is very misleading because your `http` variable is not the http module.  It's actually the result of `.createServer()` which is a server object.  I think you're using it OK, but this isn't a very good practice because most people will assume that a variable named `http` is the `http` module.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will take care, it's my first time with this, it's good to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`socket.io` connects to a server, not to a specific path.  There is no such thing as connecting to `http://www.nicolasrivero.com/2`.   socket.io connects to your server.

FYI, the URL it is using `http://nicolasrivero.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1429923179530-0` looks like a normal socket.io URL.  All webSocket connections start with an http request and this is the type of http request that socket.io registers a handler for in order to field requests for webSocket connections.

If that request is returning a 404, then that is either because your web server is not running correctly or because socket.io is not initialized correctly with the web server.  You can obviously see if the web server is operating correctly by checking other routes on the web server to see if they are working or not or by putting some debug info in your http request handler.

When socket.io is initialized correctly, it configures a handler in your web server for the /socket.io route and handles any incoming requests that target that route.

Comment: so, i should replace this,` var socket = io.connect();` with this...  `var socket = io.connect("http://www.nicolasrivero.com/2");` ... But, if it still throwing 404, i should check if my web server support socket.io ? I mean, i don't have any other webserver route with socket.io. I will try to upload to nodejitsu...

Comment: @Nicolás - No.  As I explained in my answer, you should leave it `io.connect()`.  That will connect to the server of your page.  You don't connect to a specific URL - you connect to the server.

Comment: Lol, i just read your last paragraph, so there're is indeed a route at www.nicolasrivero.com/socket.io because socket.io created it, so... I should check the webserver then, thanks

Comment: @Nicolás - yes, it seems likely the issue is on the server.  I'll take a look again at your socket.io initialization to see if anything else looks off.

Comment: @Nicolás - you are starting the server on port 3000, but the URL you show is on port 80 (the default port when no port number shows).  You you connecting to `http://www.nicolasrivero.com:3000` in the browser?

Comment: mm no, i'm just trying to connect to http://nicolasrivero.com/2/ and when i try to add :3000 it gives me a 404 not found... http://nicolasrivero.com/2/:3000 should work ?

Comment: @Nicolás - Have you established yet that your web server is working and processing normal routes (nothing to do with socket.io)?  Until you do that, there's no point in working on socket.io.  Your server is running on port 3000 so it will not work unless you use `:3000` in the browser.  `io.connect()` will pick that up automatically so you don't have to put anything there.  The proper URL would be `http://nicolasrivero.com:3000/2/`.

Comment: I don't really know how to check my webserver port, that should be the reason. The "port configurated options" it's for vip members and i don't have access, You were very helpful my friend, the last question is, if i develop aaaall my app in local host, then, Can i upload normally into a webserver? (when i pay for someone better)

Comment: @Nicolás - how you deploy your app with a given service provider depends upon the provider.  With node.js, you would have to install node and all the required libraries and the run node with your script.  The details of how you do that may vary from one hosting provider to another.   Which ports you're allowed to run on may also be specific to the provider.  You will probably want to run on port 80 to users of your site don't have to type a port number, but sometimes you run your server on a different port and the hosting provider proxies requests to your port.